# AngularJS - Directive loaded from database will not replace with a template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive coming in from a database. Similar to how shortcodes work in Wordpress, the user needs to be able to insert these custom galleries here and there. I've tried several, several ways. They compile but they do not affect the HTML on the page. What am I missing?

**Incoming from database:**

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum. Some content here</p>
<div work-gallery friendly="bq"></div>
```

I would like to replace that DIV with the "work-gallery" attribute with a template. When I load that content into the scope of my page, I compile it so my directive triggers.

**From controller**

```
$compile($scope.page.content)($scope);
```

This triggers the directive, it compiles right up to where it needs to append it or replace it and then just doesn't show up on the frontend. If I add that DIV outside of the dynamically loaded content, it works.

**Directive**

```
app.directive('workGallery', function ($compile) {
    var template = '<div>TEST{{page.med.length}}</div>';

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
            scope.page.med = [1, 2];
            scope.$watch(attrs.friendly, function () {
                ele.html(template);
                $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
                console.log(ele);
                ele.append(ele.contents());
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Inspecting "element" reveals TEST2 if I dig through down to innerText but that's all I get. Any help is appreciated! From what I understand, this should add "TEST2" within my content.

**Expected Output**

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum. Some content here</p>
<div work-gallery friendly="bq">TEST2</div>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

i think there is something wrong about watching an attribute, try:

```
attrs.$observe('friendly', function(val){
    /* .... */ 
});
```

Comment: I agree, this was based on another demo on SO. This still doesn't help with the fact that the data is not spending or replacing the original DIV. Thanks for the input though!